# Rails take base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, paperclip, base64

In rails i need to take a base64 string, and use it to generate a picture in rails. Now i'm having trouble, because i need to interact with AJAX calls (im strictly working on the server side, another guy is doing that client work) to send pictures. So far i've been taking requests in my application by having data transferred through the url (in the AJAX requests) but now im not sure if it's possible to transfer such a huge string through the url. How could i take in the data (like how could he pass it to me) to generate a picture.

Note: i've been using paperclip for my application so far, but now uploading through the form is not an option, it needs to be in an AJAX call where data is passed in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, most browsers limit the length of a URL.  The limit on IE8/9 is 2083 characters.  Even if your particular browser has a higher limit, many servers limit the URL length as well (apache's default limit is right around 8k).  It would be best to submit the image as a POST request with the data in the POST body.

I would use jQuery to POST JSON data to the server.  In the controller, if this is set up correctly, you won't have to do a thing to parse the JSON.  ActiveSupport will recognize the content type and parse it out into the params hash automatically.

Actually posting the data will depend on which javascript library you're using.  Here's an example in jQuery, which you'd probably want to wire up to the onclick event of a submit button.  This assumes you have a named route called process_image.  This code would go in your view.

```
$.post(<%= process_image_path %>, { b64_img: "your_base64_image_data" });
```

In your controller, you can access the posted data with params[:b64_img].  If you want to return something from the controller back to the client, you can do this in the controller:

```
render :json => @model_object
```

And change the jquery call to look like this so you can do something with the return value:

```
$.post(<%= process_image_path %>, { b64_img: "your_base64_image_data" }, 
  function(data) {
    // do something with the data returned by the controller
  });
```

Hope this helps.  You can read more about the jQuery post call I used here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Dan